# Obtener datos en Firestore Database

Tags: android-studio

Llevo mucho tiempo con este tema y no soy capaz de darle solucion:
Lo que quiero es imprimir(he reducido la consulta) el nom bre de las sedes y de sus subsedes algo asi

sede 1
subsede 1.1
subsede 1.2
subsede 1.3

sede 2
subsede 2.1
subsede 2.2
.
.

Pero solo imprime
sede 1
sede 2....

El codio es:

```
mfirestoreSedes = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mfirestoreSedes.collection( "Sedes").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> taskSede) {
               for (QueryDocumentSnapshot qDSedestodo : taskSede.getResult()) {
                   gmidsede = qDSedestodo.getString("idsede");
                   Log.println(qDSedestodo.getString("nombresede");
                   mfirestoreSubSedes = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                   mfirestoreSubSedes.collection( "SubSedes").whereEqualTo("idsede", gmidsede).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> taskSubsede) {
                           for (QueryDocumentSnapshot qDSubSedes : taskSubsede.getResult()) {
                               Log.println(qDSubSedes.getString("nombresubsedesede");
                           }
                       }
                   });
               }
          }
    });
```

Sucede que al ejecutar mfirestoreSubSedes.collection( "SubSedes").....lo hace asincronamente y cuando quiera devolver los datos ya ha terminado la consulta, es decir, quiero que ejecute esta sentencia y no continue con el primer for.. hasta que no me devuleta lo pedido. y asi sucesivamente cada vez que se ejecute el primer for con cada una de las sedes.

LLevo un monton de tiempo y estoy un poco desaminado.Gracias.

Comment: Si tienes un plan de pago en Firebase, este tipo de código podría darte un verdadero susto en una aplicación usada por varios miles de usuarios. [En este post](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-spent-30k-usd-in-firebase-in-less-than-72-hours-307490bd24d) se explica cómo una aplicación facturó 30,000 dólares en 72 horas debido a un error en el código. El problema de tu código es que conecta a Firebase por cada iteracción del bucle, y además, hace una consulta nueva por cada iteracción del bucle. En un contexto muy concurrente podrías tener un gran susto. Firebase es No-SQL, así que cambia el chip.

Comment: Muchas gracias. No es para miles, sino solo para unos pocos. No lo tengo de pago.  Aunque corregire el codigo.

Comment: El *quid* de la cuestión es que tu código **necesita ser optimizado**, aunque no haya riesgo de una factura enorme, si tienes un plan gratuito y el código agota los límites que tienes el día 5 del mes, tu proyecto quedará bloqueado hasta el mes siguiente. No habrá susto, pero tu App estará al menos `25` sin funcionar bien. Sea como sea, la cuestión es **optimizar** y pensar Firebase como lo que es: No-SQL, y eso supone replantearse algunas cosas como la forma de organizar los datos y de leerlos.